# How to fix "Missing or insufficient permissions at Http2CallStream"

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to update firestore document from cloud function using nodejs, but getting error

error Logs :

```
Error: Missing or insufficient permissions.
at Http2CallStream.call.on (/srv/node_modules/@grpc/grpc- 
js/build/src/client.js:101:45)
at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
at Http2CallStream.emit (events.js:211:7)
at process.nextTick (/srv/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call- 
stream.js:71:22)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
```

I tried to change the Cloud Firestore Security Rules, no success

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved this way:

1. Download the secret key from the firebase console.

[image]

2. Save the downloaded .json file in the path "./your project path/functions".
3. Add this code to the top of your index.js:

   ```
   var serviceAccount = require("./[downloaded file name].json");

   admin.initializeApp({
       credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
       databaseURL: "https://[your project id].firebaseio.com"
   });
   ```

[image]

4. Deploy the function.